# Creating a custom tag / field with Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to create a custom textrea field in Contact form 7. Were I can pre-populate it with data. I have the below which shows on the front end and creates a text area field. But when I submit the form the tag is always blank within the email so the data doesn't get emailed. The tag also does not show in the list of available tags in Contact form 7. Any ideas?

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'wpcf7_add_form_tag_pathtag' );

function wpcf7_add_form_tag_pathtag() {
  wpcf7_add_form_tag(
    array( 'pathtag', 'pathtag*'), 'pathtag_form_tag_handler',  array( 'name-attr' => true )
  );
}
function pathtag_form_tag_handler( $tag ) {

$tag = new WPCF7_FormTag( $tag );

if ( empty( $tag->name ) ) {
        return '';
    }

        $atts = array();

    $class = wpcf7_form_controls_class( $tag->type );
    $atts['class'] = $tag->get_class_option( $class );
    $atts['id'] = $tag->get_id_option();

    $atts['name'] = $tag->name;
    $atts = wpcf7_format_atts( $atts );

      $output = '';

      $output .= '<textarea cols="40" rows="10">';

          foreach ( $_SESSION['question-path'] as $path ) {

            $output .= $path ."\n\n";

          }

      $output .= '</textarea>';

       return $output;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not add the attributes to the textarea code.  Also, make sure you enter your shortcode in the contact form as

`[pathtag field-name]`

```
function pathtag_form_tag_handler($tag) {

    $tag = new WPCF7_FormTag($tag);

    if (empty($tag->name)) {
        return '';
    }

    $atts = array();

    $class = wpcf7_form_controls_class($tag->type);
    $atts['class'] = $tag->get_class_option($class);
    $atts['id'] = $tag->get_id_option();

    $atts['name'] = $tag->name;
    $atts = wpcf7_format_atts($atts);

    $output = '';

    // Make sure to add the $class and $atts to the form tag
    $output .= sprintf('<textarea cols="40" rows="10" %s %s>', $class, $atts);

    foreach ($_SESSION['question-path'] as $path) {

        $output .= $path . "\n\n";

    }

    $output .= '</textarea>';

    return $output;

}
```